# Is a single JSR203 store with a root per-commit a reasonable design for a Git filesystem layer?

Tags: java, git, jsr203

I would like to implement a jsr203 file system for accessing git history. Thus, create a path that represents a file in a specific commit, retrieve its content by letting the file system access the `.git` folder under the cover and read the history, and so on.

I have thought about using the `jgit` library to read files, and using a `Path` implementation that (mostly) delegates to the default filesystem `Path` implementation. An important difference would be that the `Path` would contain the commit identifier that the user is interested in.

I would have only one file store, but multiple roots: one per commit.

Does this design make sense? Are there hidden difficulties that I might run into? Is there more to plan before starting?

Comment: See #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, re: questions asking folks to "find or recommend" a piece of software, a library, etc.

Comment: Sorry. I have reworded to explain my problem and how I intend to address it, as suggested.

Comment: After editiion, this question absolutely does not ask to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.

Comment: I agree that it no longer fits the off-topic criteria, and have cast a vote towards reopening. That said, it could well be "too broad".

Comment: Is what you're asking for feedback on *specifically* the single-store/multiple-roots/unmodified-Path design? I might retitle to something like "Is a single JSR203 store with a root per-commit a reasonable design for a Git filesystem layer?" in that case, just to be very explicit about narrowing the focus as much as possible.

Comment: Followed suggestion.